# Ktor String response cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor

I just moved from volley requests to ktor in my native android application.
Now I have the problem, that the string response cannot be converted to JSONObject.

Got a simple class like this (I little shortend):

```
data class LoginResult(
    val success: Boolean,
    val token : String,
    val userId: UUID?,
    val tokenExpirationTime: LocalDateTime?
)
{
    companion object {
        fun fromJson(json: String) : LoginResult{
            val obj = JSONObject(json)

            var userId: UUID? = UUID.fromString(obj.getString("userId"))
            var expirationTime: LocalDateTime.parse(obj.getString("expiration"), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss"))

            return LoginResult(
                obj.getBoolean("success"),
                obj.getString("token"),
                userId,
                expirationTime
            )
        }
    }
}
```

And my request looks like that:

```
val client = HttpClient(CIO)
val response = client.post<String> {
                 url(Url.RefreshLogin)
                 addDefaultHeaders(this)
               }
val loginResult = LoginResult.fromJson(response)
```

When running that code I got this exception:

org.json.JSONException: Value {\"success\":true,\"token\":\"myToken\",\"userId\":\"2e181dac-416d-4668-b647-762e6596962a\",\"expiration\":\"2022.02.01 22:15:12\"} of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

The backend didn't change and the volley request worked fine before.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the response String has quotes at the beginning and at the end.
When I cut those off with `response.substring(1, response.length - 1)` I got another error:

Expected literal value at character 1 of {\"success\"...

The problem is, that the library escaped the quotes in the json wrong.
So I replaced the escaped characters.

Working solution:

```
var fixedJson = response.substring(1, response.length - 1)
fixedJson = fixedJson.replace("\\\"", "\"")

val loginResult = LoginResult.fromJson(fixedJson )
```